# How to add subscripts and subscripts to coordinates in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wish to use exponential form in matplotlib's coordinates. So I use the `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(y_update_scale_value))`. In my case, exponents are variables. So in the `y_update_scale_value(temp, position)` function, I use the `'2$^{}$'.format(int(temp))` as the return value. But in the image, only the highest bit of the exponent becomes superscript, and the others remain unchanged. The picture below is the effect. It's very ugly, and how should I modify it?

[image]